# How do you use Elrte Rich Text Area with Vue

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, richtextarea

Note: I am new to Learning Vue

I am trying to use the html text area with Vue. All of the other input fields are working, but I am unable to make this work.

```
<!--Description begin-->
<div id="WYSIWYG_Editor_-_Full_Options" class="control-group row-fluid">
<div class="span3">
    <label class="control-label">Description</label>
</div>
<div class="span9">
    <div class="controls elrte-wrapper">
        <textarea id="description" rows="2" name="description" class="auto-resize" v-model="form.description"></textarea>
        <script>
            $('#descrtipion').elrte({
                lang: "en",
                styleWithCSS: false,
                height: 200,
                toolbar: 'maxi'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!--Description end-->
```

This is my Vue file:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#news',
    data: {
    form: new Form({
        heading: '',
        description: '',
    }),
    imageclass: '',
    errors: new Errors()
},

methods: {
    onSubmit() {
        this.form.submit('post', '/news/'+id);
    }
},

created(){
    axios.get('/news/'+id).then(response => [
        form.heading            = response.data.heading,
        form.description        = response.data.description,
    ]);
  }
});
```

I found several solutions online but nothing is working for me. Can someone help me to make this work.

Comment: First issue I see is you're binding your Vue instance to `news` but I don't see an element with the id `news`.  Second, you should look into [wrapping the jQuery-based library](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) you want to use.

Comment: @PatrickSteele news id is the top level so it is on the full form. My text editor is a section of the full form. Sorry for the confusion but other input fields in the form i.e "heading" is working.

Comment: Perhaps you need to include more details in your question.  :)  If you're binding Vue to the `news` id, that entire DOM node (and all its children) is under Vue's control -- you can't inject a jQuery component in the middle of that.  Instead, see my link for an example of wrapping a jQuery component into a Vue component.